# Prevent terminal background from leaking through

Tags: colorscheme, redraw, kitty-terminal

A black or dark gray background seems to leak into my Vim instance on cells where there are no characters.

Is there any way to prevent this, and to use the color scheme background instead, other than using autocommand to call `:redraw!` often? (And if the autocommand is the best route, when is the ideal way to trigger it?)

[image: Dark grey terminal background leaks through on no-character cells]

Answer (score 2):

I am using the Kitty terminal, so I looked through their issues, and there is a fix for this described [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/108).

The following line should be added to the `.vimrc`:

```
" vim hardcodes background color erase even if the terminfo file does
" not contain bce (not to mention that libvte based terminals
" incorrectly contain bce in their terminfo files). This causes
" incorrect background rendering when using a color theme with a
" background color.

let &t_ut=''
```

This change works for me.